# Increase the width of a border for a shape in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a canvas and I used Javascript to create a circle within the canvas. I used `stroke()` to give the circle a border, but I am not sure how to increase the width of the border. I thought I could use `strokeWidth()`, but I am not sure.

```js
var c=document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx=c.getContext('2d');
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle="blue";
ctx.arc(150,73,70,0,2*Math.PI);
ctx.fill();
ctx.strokeStyle="yellow";
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();
```

```css
#canvas{
  height: 250px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: orange;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=500 height=250></canvas>
```

Comment: I think you are looking for `lineWidth`.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_strokestyle.asp

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can increase the thickness of the border using `.lineWidth` property like so:

---

```js
var c = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
ctx.arc(150, 73, 70, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.fill();
ctx.lineWidth = 10;
ctx.strokeStyle = "yellow";
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();
```

```css
#canvas {
  height: 250px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: orange;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=500 height=250></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `ctx.lineWidth=10;` more info can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_linewidth.asp).

Answer (score -1):

You can increase the thickness of the border using .lineWidth property like:

```
ctx.lineWidth = 10;
```

**Note: The lineWidth property must be set before calling stroke().**

Comment: let's avoid repeating the same answer again and again